# YouTube video not playing ads on iOS app

Tags: swift, webview, youtube, ads

I am building an app that plays YouTube videos.  I have used the following swift code and it plays YouTube videos successfully:

```
let pageUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDS4Y65AYT5yJTCHFytaYDPDaXLVthb-I"
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:pageUrl)!))
```

However, the videos that play never contain any of the YouTube ads that I have selected to play at the start of the video.  Anyone know how to fix this so adverts still play?

Comment: Do you have an ad-block installed?

Comment: No I don't Ravenix.

Comment: Any fix on this issue?